# Given a function, how to obtain a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could obtain a differential equation upon eliminating arbitrary constants from this equation $y = e^x(A \cos x + B \sin x)$. Here are the steps.
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = e^x(A \cos x + B \sin x) + e^x(-A \sin x + B \cos x) = y +e^x(-A \sin x + B \cos x)$$

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{dy}{dx} + e^x(-A \sin x + B \cos x) + e^x(-A \cos x - B \sin x) = \frac{dy}{dx}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} - y\right) - y ,$$

or $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = 0 $$
which is the required differential equation.

Now how do I obtain a differential equation for this one: $y = cx + c^2$? 
I am assuming $c$ is some arbitrary constant. Here are the steps that I've tried.
 $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = c$$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 0 $$ and I am stuck.

I am having trouble with this one too: $y = Ae^{3x} + Be^{2x}$ where A and B are constants.Let me edit this.For the above function differentiating w.r.t x first time gives
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 3Ae^{3x} + 2Be^{2x}$$
Differentiating again w.r.t x gives $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 9Ae^{3x} + 4Be^{2x}$$ What next?

All Right, I've edited as per request. And also I corrected the pointed mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The derivative of $cx+c^2$ with respect to $x$ is just $c$... the exponential solution with two constants requires you to differentiate twice.

Comment: As for the question in the title: for general functions, it can be very hard to do...

Comment: @alok, why don't you try typesetting the math in TeX (and I don't mean this in a negative way)? It's quite simple: the first step is simply to enclose the math expressions inside dollar (\$) signs. E.g., \$ e^x (A cos x + sin x) \$. This wouldn't be perfect, but would be a good first step; you can always improve once you're more comfortable.

Comment: @Arturo There seems to have been too many simultaneous edits to the question, and I think I should take the blame. Also, one of your edits perhaps just disappeared because of mine. I apologize for this :-) (I hadn't noticed you made the changes until after I submitted mine.)

Comment: @Srivatsan: Yours seems good enough. No worries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for your first question, you just need to substitute $c$ in your first equation:

$$
y = y'x + (y')^2
$$

and you already have a differential equation whose general solution is your function $y = cx + c^2$. (Check this!)

As for the second one, since it depends on two parameters, $A$ and $B$, it's a solution of a second order differential equation. So you should derive two times:

\begin{aligned}
y   &=    Ae^{3x} + B e^{2x}  \\
y'  &=   3Ae^{3x} + 2B e^{2x} \\
y'' &=   9Ae^{3x} + 4B e^{2x}
\end{aligned}

Now, you look at these equalities as one between vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\
y' \\
y''
\end{pmatrix}
=
A
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{3x} \\
3e^{3x} \\
9e^{3x}
\end{pmatrix}
+
B
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{2x}  \\
2e^{2x}  \\
4e^{4x}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This way, they say that you have three linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So their determinant must be zero:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
y   &   e^{3x}    &  e^{2x}  \\
y'  &  3e^{3x}    &  2e^{2x}  \\
y'' &  9e^{3x}    &  4e^{2x}
\end{vmatrix}
= 0
$$

And this is your second order differential equation.

EDIT. More explicitly, computing this determinant, we get:

$$
0 = 
y 
\begin{vmatrix}
3e^{3x}   &   2e^{2x}  \\
9e^{3x}   &   4e^{2x}
\end{vmatrix}
-y' 
\begin{vmatrix}
e^{3x}    &   e^{2x}  \\
9e^{3x}   &  4e^{2x}
\end{vmatrix}
+y'' 
\begin{vmatrix}
e^{3x}    &   e^{2x}  \\
3e^{3x}   &  2e^{2x}
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Etc.

Comment: Oh yaa..Silly me..

Comment: @alok: Another possibility would be the differential equation $y''=0$. This has more solutions than the required one, though.

Comment: I have no idea as to what to do.All i'am able to do is differentiate the same function twice and leave it as it is.

Comment: @Agusti:The back of my text gives d^2y/dx^2 - 5dy/dx + 6y = 0 How do i obtain this?

Comment: Thinking a little bit.  :-)

Comment: @alok  Simplify the final equation in the answer by evaluating each determinant. Then you should be able to cancel off a $e^{3x} \cdot e^{2x} = e^{5x}$ factor from the equation to get exactly what you wanted.